# How to make android dialog modal?

Tags: android, dialog, modal-dialog

I implemented this custom AlertDialog like so:

```
AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setView(dialogView)
    .setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.addedit_asklater_price))
    .setCancelable(false)
    .create();

    dialog.setMessage(text);
    dialog.setOwnerActivity(this);
    dialog.setButton(...)
    dialog.setButton(...)
    dialog.show();

    doProcessUserInput();
```

However, I notice that after the `dialog.show()` control immediately flows to `doProcessUserInput()` without waiting for the user to dismiss the dialog using any of the dialog buttons.

This behavior seems bizarre, I was expecting the dialog to be modal, in the way I have always known modal dialogs to be.

I can restructure my code so that `doProcessUserInput()` is called from the dialog button's `onClickListener`. I was however wondering if there was a way to pause program execution at `dialog.show()` untill the dialog is finished.

PS:

1. I've tried using a Custom Dialog that extends Dialog, but it has the
   same problem.  I am creating the dialog in a button's
   `onClickListener`.
2. I've tried implementing the `Activity::onCreateDialog` and using `showDialog(id)` instead of `dialog.show()`, but that has the same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Surely, you can set up `onPositiveButton` click listener for your dialog and do your action from that listener.

If you indeed want to pause your activity at a certain point you, probably, can use the old java `wait/notify` mechanism or more convenient new mechanisms such as executors.

Why would you want to do that though is not clear. Android dialogs are specifically designed to be non-modal so that they can in no way  block your application (as your application can include other activities such as native Phone Call activity and it would be bad if those get blocked).

Comment: Hmm... makes sense now. Hadn't thought about this angle. Comes from the cobwebs of a lifetime of desktop programming.

Answer (score 4):

This works for me: create an Activity as your dialog.  Then,

1. Add this to your manifest for the activity:

   android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
2. Add this to onCreate of your activity

   setFinishOnTouchOutside (false);
3. Override onBackPressed in your activity:

   @Override
   public void onBackPressed()
   {
     // prevent "back" from leaving this activity
   }

The first gives the activity the dialog look.  The latter two make it behave like a modal dialog.

Comment: I looked everywhere for this one simple line  setFinishOnTouchOutside (false);
Thank you!  And overriding onBackPressed() was perfect, as well!

Answer (score 4):

Before calling the dialog show() method, try calling **.setCancelable(false)**. That worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 2):

Furthermore, you shouldn't block the application flow in a dialog.

Android dev guide and community best practices states that if you want something modal, you **have to** do it in the `onClickListener`s.